# Docker inside Docker (without command line)

Tags: bash, docker, dockerfile, docker-image

I want to run docker daemon inside my docker image. I know I can easily achieve this by exposing outer docker process during running my docker image, but unfortunately I have no possibility to control how my image is run. I CAN NOT use DIND.

Therefore I would like to start docker service inside either Dockerfile or some script that is my entrypoint. I tried invoking command:

```
CMD service docker start
```

after downloading and installing docker in the image and also including this command in some script `start.sh` and calling it:

```
ENRYPOINT ["path/to/script/start.sh"]
```

None of this worked. Is it at all possible to run docker as I want or am I doing something incorrectly or it is just not possible in my execution environment?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Per your requirements, you can't.

To run the docker service inside of a docker container, you need to modify how the container is launched to give the inner docker service privileges the outer docker service restricts by default.

Comment: Ok, thanks. I was afraid that it can be impossible. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest to use the DIND Container (Docker in Docker)

```
docker run --privileged --name some-docker -d docker:1.8-dind
```

Link to Docker Hub: https://hub.docker.com/_/docker/

Comment: I said I am not able to configure the way of running the container so I can't use DIND.